# Closest point to triangle edge with barycentric coordinates

Tags: barycentric-coordinates

Let's define the distance from a point $P = (x,y)^T$ to a triangle defined by $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ with $X_i = (x_i, y_i)$ as the distance to the closest edge of the triangle. Let's define $b=(u,v,w)^T$ as the berycentric coordinates of $p$, therefore

$$
p = Ub = \left[\begin{matrix}x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\ 1&1&1\end{matrix}\right]\left( \begin{matrix}u\\v\\w\end{matrix}\right)
$$

If we define $t_0$ as the projection of $p$ to the closest edge of the triangle in barycentric coordinates. Then we can define the distance $d$ as $d= |U(t_0-b)|$.

My question is how can I calculate $t_0$ in barycentric coordinates?

Comment: The distance from $P$ to the line $X_1 X_2$ is
$$\frac {2 |w_P| S_{\triangle X_1 X_2 X_3}} {X_1 X_2}$$
because $w_P$ in normalized barycentric coordinates is equal to $S_{\triangle X_1 X_2 P}/S_{\triangle X_1 X_2 X_3}$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Maxim, I was wondering if there is any solution using the elements of $U^TU$ that is $X_1X_1, X_1X_2,...$, do you know any?

Comment: The signed area of $\triangle X_1 X_2 X_3$ is $\det U/2$. The Euclidean distance matrix can be written as
$$\boldsymbol T^t \operatorname {diag}(U^t U) +
 \operatorname {diag}(U^t U)^t \, \boldsymbol T - 2 U^t U,$$
where $\boldsymbol T = \begin {pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end {pmatrix}$ and $\operatorname {diag}(A) = \begin {pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{22} & a_{33} \end {pmatrix}$.